# Multiple ajax get requests of same route but different query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have had this for a couple of days now.

I have a simple search form. When form is submitted the server searches for some data from another server and return data to the screen. When the submit completes it gets some javascript from the server based on the results returned from the search. the javascript then makes multiple concurrent jquery get requests, lets say 4, to the asp.net mvc3 webapp.

I have demonstrated that all the get requests fire at the same time in Firebug but when debugging my app with VS the breakpoints only get hit once the previous request completes.

The actions are the same but the querys are different; ie

```
/Home/Details/040801
/Home/Details/040802
/Home/Details/040803
```

So these are different URLs and, from what i found out, FF should treat them differently.

So my questions are:

1. Am I missing something obvious?
2. Does IIS have some funny blocking on the same route?
3. Is it a session cache issue? I am locking `lock (lockobject){}` on writes to the common session variables.

Im not using ViewBag or TempData.

The page load times, even when everything is cached in the Session, are still noticeably synchronous.

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Using IIS 7.5
- ASP.NET MVC 3
- VS2010 Chrome or FF browser

I have my routes set up as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "Default", // Route name
      "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
);
routes.MapRoute("Details", "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{booking}", new { id = UrlParameter.Optional, booking = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

Nothing special there as you can see.

Sample code from one of the blocked routes:

```
public ActionResult Details(string id, bool booking = false)
    {
        if (booking)
        {
            return BookingDetails(id, true);
        }
        Dictionary<string, FlightDetails> detailDic;
        string scenarioInput;

        lock (DetailsLock)
        {
            if (Session["DetailDic"] == null)
            {
                Session["DetailDic"] = new Dictionary<string, FlightDetails>();
            }
            detailDic = (Dictionary<string, FlightDetails>)Session["DetailDic"];
        }
        if (detailDic.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            return PartialView("Details", detailDic[id]);
        }

        lock (GuidLock)
        {
            if (Session["DetailGuids"] == null)
            {
                Session["DetailGuids"] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            }
            scenarioInput = ((Dictionary<string, string>)Session["DetailGuids"])[id];
        }
        // query results list
        string queryText = string.Format("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">OUT {0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", scenarioInput);
        ListItemCollection oList;
        int counter = 0;
        do
        {
            oList = SharepointHelper.GetListFromSharepoint("ListName", queryText, ClientContext);
            counter++;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        } while (oList.Count == 0 && counter <= Timeout);

        if (oList.Count == 0)
        {
            return PartialView("Details", (object)null);
        }

        var item = oList[0];

        FlightDetails flightDetails = CreateFlightDetails(id, scenarioInput, item);
        lock (DetailsLock)
        {
            detailDic.Add(id, flightDetails);
        }
        return PartialView("Details", flightDetails);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when using session object in server-side your async calls wait for session object released by other request. Becuase of this async ajax calls act like sync. You have to use session as readonly in that action.

Add this attribute to action you call if you dont write anything to session.

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```

Comment: This is a class/controller attribute but once I added it there I got the asynchronous actions. Thanks.